# Firebase Authentication Anonymous Account Creation then call function with context.auth.uid error

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I'm testing to see if the anonymous account is created and then able to call the firebase function with the user signed in.

```
[FirebaseAuth] user signed out
[FirebaseAuth] Added Listener
[FirebaseAuth] UserId :
[FirebaseAuth] Removed Listener
[FirebaseAuth] UserId :
[FirebaseAuth] Signing in as anon
[FirebaseAuth] anonymous user signed in : 4z0LPkpRHpREFy7l6PB3yqHtsyN2
[FirebaseAuth] UserId : 4z0LPkpRHpREFy7l6PB3yqHtsyN2
```

Then, I'm getting this error -

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm unclear what isn't working the way you expect.  There's not enough information here to track what you're doing on the client and how that relates to what you observe in the function.

Comment: I expect to see the context.auth.uid to be there since the anonymous account is created. Editing the question to make it clearer.

Comment: If `context.auth` is undefined, that means a user was not signed in at the time of the request.  There really isn't another explanation.  Without seeing exactly what's going on in the client code, there's nothing we can do.  Your client code should check that a user is signed in before invoking the callable, if that's what you require.

Comment: The code is checking the user id before calling the firebase function. I'm going to double check my code. I'm thinking it might be a race condition somewhere, thanks

Comment: You are correct, I didn't check the user id before calling the function. Thanks again